# Can I leave the fuel filter hose, EVAP line and all the electric lines disconnected overnight outside?

Tags: fuel-system, hose

I'm in the middle of having to drop my tank to change the fuel pump but dont have enough time to finish the job before it starts to rain tonight and tomorrow. Is it safe to leave all those hoses and lines disconnected until the rain lets up at times for me to start work again? The car in question is outside fully exposed to the elements. The negative connector is disconnected from the battery along with the relay fuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but I would plug each one - if you have the plastic bungs around then use those, if not then bolts work... even bits of rag as long as you don’t leave bits behind.

It has been known for bugs to crawl into pipes and it can cause hard to find problems when they obstruct the flow... Don’t ask how I know... :)